# Lock Quote when PDF email is sent

Tags: email, quote

I have the following requirement: When the User presses the standard "Email Quote" button and actually sends the email (doesn't cancel) the quote record must be locked.

My question is how to detect this event synchronously ? I know I can access the related ActivityHistory and check for new records with specific values, but this is asynchronous and thus there's a time period between the action (sending email) and the result (locking the record)

Any ideas ?

Comment: You might consider customizing the quote button to add some code to trigger workflow. The issue you have is do you really want to lock the record prior to actually sending the email? What happens if for some reason there's a "glitch" or a problem with the quote and it needs to be cancelled and redone?

Comment: The problem with customizing the button and having certain actions before sending the email is how to handle email sending cancellation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since there's an ActivityHistory record, there's also a Task record and this means I can lock the quote in the Task trigger